# Join the values of 2 tables

Tags: php, html, mysql, select, join

I have 2 tables and I can't merge the values of these tables into table2.

```
Table1:

id | studnum | fname | lname | mname
1  | 1001    | Mark  | Lei   | Ramos

Table2:

id | studnum | remarks
```

Is it possible that when I input the values into Table2, the studnum from Table1 will input into Table2 also?

I tried this but it doesn't worked.

```
 $sql = "SELECT table1.studnum FROM table1, table2
         WHERE table1.studnum = table2.studnum";
```

So that the Table2 will be like this output

```
 id | studnum | remarks
 1  | 1001    | good
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is using a JOIN Statement.

If the shared key is between them is studnum, you can do

```
SELECT * FROM table1
JOIN table2
ON table1.studnum = table2.studnum
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a MySQL join function. Example:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
JOIN table2
ON table1.studnum=table2.studnum;
```

More reading on joins: http://www.keithjbrown.co.uk/vworks/mysql/mysql_p5.php

Answer (score 0):

If those are exactly your tables you dont really need what you are requesting as it goes against normalization.

In the case you will only have one or none remarks for an entry in table 1 there is no need for table 2, the remarks should be in table 1.

In the case you need multiple remarks for a single entry in table 1, you dont need stdnum in table 2. If your problem in this scenario is to construct a query to get the remakrs based on stdnums you can easily achieve this with a joint.

The only field you should be duplicating from table to table for a record/object is the id. You can (and may be should) scrifice normalization in pro of efficiency but your example is not the case.